# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str What is the problem of my code

Tags: string, list, types, integer, indices

This is the program.

```py
    """Program for calculate the average height """
    student_height = input("Insert you heights here:").split()
    
    #Now convert list into integer
    for n in student_height:
        student_height[n] = int(student_height[n])
    print(f"Heights are: {student_height}")
    
    # Now total of the heights avoide sum()
    total_heights = 0
    for height in student_height:
        total_heights += height
    
    # Now count students from list student_height avoid len()
    total_student = 0
    for student in student_height:
        total_student += 1
    
    # Now calculate the average height.
    average = round(total_heights / total_student)
    print(f"Average height is: {average}")
```

The error I am getting.

```py
Insert you heights here:170 180
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    student_height[n] = int(student_height[n])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
➜
```

may be something in here. But what?. Very hard to find errors as a beginner. please help anyone.

```py
#Now convert list into integer
for n in student_height:
    student_height[n] = int(student_height[n])
print(f"Heights are: {student_height}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your code:

```
  
    #Now convert list into integer
    for n in student_height:
        student_height[n] = int(student_height[n])
    print(f"Heights are: {student_height}")
```

`student_height` is a list of strings.

Therefore, `n` would be a string and not an integer.
What you need to do is the following:

```
  
    #Now convert list into integer
    for n in range(len(student_height)):
        student_height[n] = int(student_height[n])
    print(f"Heights are: {student_height}")
```

Or, I hazard a guess that you could even do the following:

```
student_height = [int(x) for x in student_height]
```

But this lacks any error checking so if you add something non-integer, you'd get a ValueError or somesuch.  But then again,
you'd get the same error with the new code.  So I'm just assuming
that the user will input valid integers.